# Rails nested params not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question model and answer model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

Here are the params I'm sending for the #update call to `QuestionsController`:

```
{"id"=>"1", "text"=>"Hello world?", 
"answers"=>[{"id"=>1, "text"=>"Answer 4", "question_id"=>1]}
```

Pretty straightforward. The update method:

```
def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    if @question.update(q_params)
      render :json => @question
    else
      not_valid @question
    end
  end
```

Now here's the part that I'm struggling tragically with: I want to whitelist these params. I can't control the param names, so I can't rename `answers` to `answers_attributes`. The only thing I have found to work, which is a little ridiculous, is this:

```
  def q_params
    p = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(params)
    p[:answers_attributes] = p.delete :answers
  end
```

I really want to do this the right way, using just `permit`. Here's a combination of lines I've tried, none of which work:

```
params.permit(:text, {:answers_attributes => [:text]})
# or
permitted = [:text, answers_attributes: [:id, :text]]
params.permit(*permitted)
# or
params.permit(:text, {:answers => [:text]})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:id, :text, answers_attributes: [:id, :text])
end
```

and for updating

```
def update
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  if @question.update_attributes(question_params)
    render :json => @question
  else
    not_valid @question
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers` and `question_form.fields_for :answers do |answer_form|` will generate the `associations_attributes` params that you area looking for.

> expecting that `question_form` is smth like `form_for @question do |question_form`

Comment: `.require(:question)` I don't have a question param coming in. The params I'm posting are in the question above and they're not changeable. That's the whole purpose for this question.